# Solving an inequality using the Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

**Question** Prove using the mean value theorem that $$\lvert \arcsin(a)-\arcsin(b) \rvert \ge \lvert b-a\rvert$$ for all $a,b\in (\frac{1}{2},1) $

**My attempt**

By the mean value theorem we have that

$\frac{ \arcsin(b)-\arcsin(a)}{b-a} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}$

However this is where I am encountering the problem. I have that

$0 \lt \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2}} \lt \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$,

however this doesn't tell me anything? Is there any other way I could approach this?

Comment: Can you really not do better for the lower bound?

Comment: I don't think so? Am I missing something?

Comment: I think I see where I have made my mistake, am I correct in saying the lower bound of c is not 0 but you have $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \lt \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2}} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $c \in (a,b)$, $ 0 < c < 1 \Rightarrow 1-c^2 < 1 \Rightarrow \sqrt{1-c^2} < 1 \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2}} > 1$. This implies the result.